# MathJax in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, mathjax

I have a Jupyter notebook installed on a works windows laptop which I have tried to render some laytex for math formula.  I get this [image: Formula with brackets]

The brackets should expand to cover the fractions under the square rooot and with the last term.  I thought it was a font issue and installed Stix font on the machine but that had no affect also I tried \Left( and \Right) but that breaks the render.

The laytex code is

$$ I_t \geq \frac{1}{C_aC_sC_dC_i}\sqrt{ ({\frac{I_n}{C_fC_c})^2 }}+0.48I_b^2(\frac{1-C_g^2}{C_g^2})$$

I have searched but I am not finding the solution how do you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after way too much searching so

$$ I_t \geq \frac{1}{C_aC_sC_dC_i}\sqrt{\biggl ({\frac{I_n}{C_fC_c}\biggr)^2 }}+0.48I_b^2\biggl(\frac{1-C_g^2}{C_g^2}\biggr )$$

the \bigg ifound on https://bearnok.com/grva/en/knowledge/software/mathjax

Under manual adjustment which is contary to laytex , I think, but solves my issue!

[image: Formula fixed]

Comment: You can also use `\left(...\right)` around the fraction in order to have the size of the parentheses selected automatically.

Comment: I did try that didn’t seem to work in Jupyter notebook.

Comment: I don't see any reason that it wouldn't, but I don't use Jupiter notebook.  Can you be more explicit about what "didn't seem to work" means?  Was there an error message of any kind?  The entire expression not being typeset?  the parens being just the normal size, or what?

Comment: It breaks the render and just shows the code no error messages.

Comment: OK, still seems strange.  Can you inspect the DOM element for the expression and see if there is anything unusual there (like a DOM element within the expression)?  That's the only thing I can think of that would interfere with MathJax typesetting the expression.  Unless Jupyter notebook is locating the math itself and rendering each expression separately, in which case it may be its own algorithm that is not working in this case, and not MathJax's.